# Spring REST same endpoint with and without token

Tags: java, spring, rest

The following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activated",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public GameHolder getAllGames(){
        return gameService.getActivatedGames();
    }
```

gets me some games and this path can be requested without token (WebSecurityConifugurerAdapter):

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //Add Paths which should be ignored by authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/games/activated");
}
```

But i call the userService and load some extra data if a user is logged in, but the problem now is, because of the ignoring() it ignores completely the authentication, how can I enter authentication when a token is provided?

I hope you understand what I mean

## Edit1

My "doFilterInternal" looks like:

```
    @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
                try{
                    if(authorization != null && !authorization.isEmpty() && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith(tokenType.toLowerCase() + " ")){
                        String[] tokenTypeAndToken = authorization.split(" ");
                        final UserAuthentication tokenAuthentication = new UserAuthentication();
                        tokenAuthentication.setCredentials(tokenTypeAndToken[1]);
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationManager.authenticate(tokenAuthentication));
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"No token provided!");
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
               

 }
```

Comment: Well, once you ignore it.. it will always be ignored.

Comment: yes i know and that's the reason for my question, I dont want to write to endpoints one for authenticated users and one for not logged in users

Comment: I am looking for the answers, too

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding `configure(HttpSecurity http)`, & instead of ignoring it, try to `permitAll`. I am using same for my use cases similar to this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/games/activated").permitAll()
}
```

Comment: It gets me to the authenticate method, but there I have to specify the path I guess? Edit above

Comment: you can get the current authenticated user using SecurityContext.

Comment: Ah sorry I mean doFilterInterl not authentication

Comment: So have you implemented manually this method ? for what purpose.

Comment: More or less manually, I overrided it from the AuthenticationProvider interface. For what reason? I guess this should be readable, to authenticate the user and set it in the SecurityContextHolder.

Comment: I guess that is done by spring security already. why do you need to override it ?

Comment: no it isn't, that's why... Spring Security does not automatically authenticate / load a User from an external USerService  for instance Facebook or Google